# Add RotateTransform animation to Storyboard in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have the following animation defined in code-behind:

```
DoubleAnimation dbAscending = new DoubleAnimation(0, 15, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)));
(myImage.RenderTransform as RotateTransform).BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, dbAscending);
```

This works fine, when started it rotates `myImage` by 15 degrees. Now I just need to create new `Storyboard` and add the animation into it, because I need to use its `Completed` event. I have a little problem with that, I noticed that I can add the animation to `Storyboard.Children`, but I didn't managed to define the object and property I want to apply this animation to...

Thanks in advance for any help, until now I created storyboards only in XAML...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the Storyboard-attached properties on the animation, something like:

```
DoubleAnimation dbAscending = new DoubleAnimation(0, 15, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)));
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(dbAscending);
Storyboard.SetTarget(dbAscending, myImage);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dbAscending, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Angle"));
```

(*untested; could also directly target the transform and reduce path to angle*)